# Is their any way to give the information by python to java script back in given module?

Tags: python-3.8

```
def calculate(a,b):
    answer = a + b
    your = answer
```

this is a module i created for a calculator. I want to display the answer on `html` web page by `java script` through eel.
So my question is that how can i give the information back to `java script` by `python(eel)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel) for eel it looks like you can try this:

On the line before your `calculate()` function in your Python source add a decorator `@eel.expose`

```py
@eel.expose
def calculate(a, b):
    answer = a + b
    return answer
```

Your Javascript source (lifted directly from the documentation will look roughly like this):

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="eel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
// Call a Python function, passing the numbers four and five and then creating an alert with the answer
      alert(eel.calculate(4, 5)); 
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello, World!
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for this code, I think you can create the same method in javascript as well. use the following code

```
function calculate(x,y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Then, you can call this function as `var answer = calculate(5,6)`. this will return answer to the variable.